# Java ternary operator datatype conversion based on the first value?

Tags: java, operators

I came across this thing which I havent noticed before.

Here is a normal expression

```
    int a = 5;
                  System.out.println(((a < 5) ? 0 : 9));
```

so this just prints 9 as an int. Now If I put the first value String instead of an int 0

```
    int a = 5;
                  System.out.println(((a < 5) ? "asd" : 9));
```

Here the value 9 is printed as a string and not as an int. To confirm this just try to add this with another integer

```
 int a = 5;
             System.out.println((((a < 5) ? 0 : 9) + 4)           );
```

Now this results in 13 but if you change the first value to string instead of an int 0 it gives a compile error

```
"The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Object&Serializable&Comparable<?>, int".
```

I am confused with this compile error. What is actually behind this ? Thanks for explanation

Comment: This is fully-described [in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), and absolutely not worth reproducing here. TL;DR: the result of the *conditional* operator is the least upper bound of the second and third operands.

Comment: I didnt know this so was confused, anyways thanks for clarifying.

Comment: if you think this is confusing, try to work out the type of `Object result = true ? Integer.valueOf(0) : Double.valueOf(0);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of

```
(a < 5) ? "asd" : 9
```

is

```
Object&Serializable&Comparable<?>
```

You can see this in the compiler error later in the question. The `int` `9` is boxed to `Integer` and then the common type between that and `String` is found. So you are actually calling the `println(Object)` overload not `println(String)` or `println(int)`. `println(Object)` calls `toString` on its argument.

If you try to apply `+` to a `Object&Serializable&Comparable<?>` then neither string concatenation or arithmetic is applicable, hence the compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the expression `(a < 5) ? "asd" : 9` depends on the types of the 2nd and 3rd operands - "asd" and 9. The only common type to those two operands is `Object` (if the `int` is boxed to `Integer`).

Therefore the type of the expression is `Object`, Java has no `+` operator that accepts `Object` and `int` as operands. Hence the compilation error.

In

```
System.out.println((((a < 5) ? 0 : 9) + 4));
```

the type of the ternary conditional expression is `int`, and `int` and `int` are acceptable operands of the `+` operator.